# OrientDB: how to fetch neighbor vertices of a particular class

Tags: orientdb

Assume I have three classes of vertices `Person`, `Teacher`, `Parent`, and an edge class `Teaches`. A `person` might have several incoming `Teaches` edges from either `Teacher` or `Parent`.

I would like to fetch the `teacher_id` and `parent_id`individually along with each `Person` by SQL query. That means, I only want to get the ID of `Teacher` or `Parent` who teaches the `Person` for each record.

I have tried below SQL but it could probably get both `Teacher` and `Parent` record IDs.

`SELECT *, in('Teaches') FROM Person`

Does any one have any idea about this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
select * , in('Teaches') as teacherParent from Person unwind teacherParent
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I want, either. This SQL splits the collection into records, but question is, how to identify which records are desired ones?

Comment: try select * ,in('Teaches')[@class="Teacher"].teacher_id,in('Teaches')[@class="Parent"].parent_id from Person

Comment: Exactly what I want! Thank you @alessandro-rota

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select in.*,out.* from (select expand(inE('Teaches')) FROM Person)
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I want. I want to get the associate teacher_id along with the properties of person.

Comment: Have you executed that query? can you post a couple of results?

Comment: Yes, it looks like expand OUT and IN vertices including those I don't want, and that may consume too much resources.. anyways, thanks for the help :D